# Correct InstallUtil Path To File Syntax?

Tags: syntax, .net-2.0, path, batch-file, installutil

I'm trying to install a Windows Service using a batch file, let's call it "installservice.bat". Inside the file I have the following commands:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe -i ".\MyService.exe"
    pause
```

When I excute the batch file (running as administrator on Vista) I get this:

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Win
dows\system32\MyService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot f
ind the file specified..
```

The actual service is located at C:\Services\MyService.exe. What should the ".\MyService.exe" part be for it to function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just feed InstallUtil the full path?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case someone else comes here for this error...  when you run InstallUtil.exe, **if the path to your service contains spaces, surround it with quotes.**  Yes this is obvious, but the error it gives you if you don't is not.

wrong...

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe C:\Users\joeblow\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
```

right...

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe "C:\Users\joeblow\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the bat file MyService.exe folder and execute, you wont get any error.